# Install nvidia-legacy 304.137 driver on Elementary OS Hera

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Is it possible to install Latest Legacy GPU version (304.xx series): 304.137 nvidia driver on elementary 5.1? On Freya it was possible but no such luck here on Hera.

I have the old GPU: `NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a]`

Since Elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera is based on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS I heard that there is a patched version for the `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.137.run` driver but I tried the option and still got an error (unable to build kernel module) from nvidia prompt.